# How to configure Service Auto-scaling in AWS ECS (using step scaling)

Tags: amazon-web-services, rabbitmq, amazon-ecs, aws-auto-scaling

We have a number of dotNet services running in ECS which consume data from RabbitMQ queues, I want to scale up the number of instances based on the number of messages in the queues.

Let's say I want to have one instance running if the queue is below 100, two instances for 100-199 and so on up to 500+ (5 instances).  [The values here are for example purposes only]

I have created a CloudWatch Alarm which monitors the queue in question and goes into alarm when it hits 100.

I have enabled the service auto-scaling, set the min (1) and max (5) and created a scaling policy which monitors that alarm and sets the scaling actions as follows...

```
Add 1 task from 100 to 200
Add 1 task from 200 to 300
Add 1 task from 300 to 400
Add 1 task from 400 to +infinity
```

This appears to work though I do seem to see more instances than I expect sometimes.

What I cannot work out is how to scale down correctly.  If I add another policy for scale down, as follows...

```
Remove 1 task from 100 to 200
Remove 1 task from 200 to 300
Remove 1 task from 300 to 400
Remove 1 task from 400 to +infinity
```

...I see the number of tasks bouncing up and down (say) between two and three when the messages are perhaps at 250.

Can someone please point me to a good example of how exactly to set this up.  I've found a number of articles which skirt round the edges but can't find that one decent example of exactly how to configure this scenario.

Your help would be much appreciated.

Comment: I think you should only be creating a single step scaling policy, and instead of setting the scaling action to "add 1 task" you should be setting a specific desired task count for each step.

Comment: It's a bit confusing to me, because the actual API for creating these policies doesn't allow you to specify "add" or "remove" like the UI does, the API requires you to specify a "scaling adjustment value" that is used for both adding and removing tasks, so I'm not sure what the UI is even doing when you specify "add" or "remove". You could query the API to see what is actually being created by the UI: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/application-autoscaling/describe-scaling-policies.html

Comment: I've found I can achieve the scale up quite easily. This works for us if set with a timeout of 60 seconds. The scale down can only be achieved with the alarms interface but can set the number of tasks to one when it gets below a certain level - a cumbersome approach but workable until I have the time for a more elegant solution.